# Is there a process logging tool for solaris?

Tags: solaris, monitoring, process-management

Is there an existing tool for solaris/unix that keeps a history trail of the list of running processes. I'd like to be able to review backwards in time what processes were active/running.

I can create a cron job that just regularly logs the output of ps into files, but this is crude and over a large server farm seems inefficient and can create many files.

And I need full command arguments so it has to be /usr/ucb/ps auxww output, ideally with cpu times, state, rss, pid, ppid, zone information.

Also, if possible the output should be easy to parse--e.g. in a consistent delimited format or some other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use auditing.

[Solaris Auditing (Overview)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4557/auditov-1/index.html)

> Auditing generates audit records when specified events occur. Most
>   commonly, events that generate audit records include the following:
>
> - System startup and system shutdown
> - Login and logout
> - Process creation or process destruction, or thread creation or thread destruction
> - Opening, closing, creating, destroying, or renaming of objects
> - Use of privilege capabilities or role-based access control (RBAC)
> - Identification actions and authentication actions
> - Permission changes by a process or user
> - Administrative actions, such as installing a package
> - Site-specific applications
>
> Audit records are generated from three sources:
>
> - By an application
> - As a result of an asynchronous audit event
> - As a result of a process system call

A good blog article on Solaris auditing can be found [here](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=647).